# Convert S3 object modified time to localtime in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am retreiving S3 objects through code below and deleteing the objects belonging to previous day:

```
 today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
 s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1')
 s3_objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket='bucket', Prefix ='path/to/folder/')
 for o in s3_objects["Contents"]:
     if o["LastModified"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') != today:
         s3.delete_object(Bucket='bucket', Key=o['Key'])
```

However, S3 objects modified timestamp is in UTC, hence I am not getting wanted results. I can change current timestamp to local timestamp using pytz:

`datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Using same on o["LastModified"] is not working and giving error `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable`

One solution is simply adding time difference hours but can't do that because of different time difference with UTC due to day light saving.

Can anyone please help me with, how to convert S3 object modified date to local timestamp (CET)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace 
    `if o["LastModified"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') != today:`

with
    `if o["LastModified"].astimezone(pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') != today:`